# Is there any danger in booting an existing Windows 10 in a VM on separate SSD and accessing a shared data partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, windows

I was looking into booting into my existing W10 installation that is already on a separate SSD from my Ubuntu installation on a dual-boot machine, as in: [Running a real Windows install in VirtualBox on Linux](https://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2016/02/running-a-real-windows-install-in-virtualbox-on-linux/)

All of my data/documents are stored on a 3rd HDD, such that

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  NTFS Windows 10 LTSC install (noauto,nouser)
/dev/sda1       exFAT shared data partition (currently mounted at boot by Ubuntu)
/dev/sdb1       Ubuntu 20.04 install
```

Is there any risk in having the shared data partition on `/dev/sda1` mounted simultaneously by both the VM and Ubuntu? Will I be likely to lose data on this HDD by using it this way? If so, is there an alternative way of setting this up to make it safer? I pretty much need both OS to be able to access this data partition.

**Edit**: The data partition contains MySQL data and htdocs folder. It also contains some Office files (Word/Excel etc) that I need to open. It also contains some Office files (Word/Excel etc) that I need to open. I'd only have one instance of LAMP/XAMPP stack running at a time. I am more worried about the Office files being corrupted by possibly being accessed from both machines at once.

Comment: Welcome to AsK Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1261144/edit) and indicate in the **question above** what kind of data you are talking about? Is it data in SQL type databases, or is it Word, Excel, Music, Video etc. files? Databases that are accessed via the web browsers may be fine but other files opened and changed from two systems at the same time can get corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use multiple OS on the same data every day. Dual-boot vs. virtualization will make no difference. Your *workflow* is what keeps your data integrity.

If your data is in a database, then it's easy: Responding to read/write queries from multiple sources is what database applications do. One application on one OS owns the database - all other applications on all OS communicate with that application (not the data directly).

If your data is in non-database tables and files, then you must create your own rules for which applications are allowed to read/write (and when). Keeping different applications from trying to read/write the same file at the same time is mostly an exercise in scheduling.

Comment: Edited my question as above: The data partition contains MySQL data and htdocs folder. It also contains some Office files (Word/Excel etc) that I need to open. I'd only have one instance of LAMP/XAMPP running at a time.

Comment: I don't see that change anything in the answer.  Your risk still comes from complexity, not  whether you virtualize or dual-boot.